# Directional transition mouse-event area seems to be offset in Chrome?

Tags: jquery, css, google-chrome

I just finished building a Jquery directional gallery and i went to test it on chrome and the
directional transition seems to be offset from the mouse position [see jsfiddle in chrome](http://jsfiddle.net/unknown601/wL6rLsmq/16/). Here is the code i currently have.

I think it might be something wrong with the way it calculates the mouse direction?

(it works perfectly in Firefox and IE 10)

I have tried changing the container (#gallery-container) from absolute to relative and static with no luck.

I am Pretty sure its something to do with the var x and var y, but i'm not a expert in jQuery.

```
var x = (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - (w / 2)) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1);
          var y = (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - (h / 2)) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1);
```

---

JQuery

```
    $(".gallery li").on("mouseenter mouseleave", function (e) {

      var w = $(this).width();
      var h = $(this).height();

      var x = (e.pageX - $(this).offset().left - (w / 2)) * (w > h ? (h / w) : 1);
      var y = (e.pageY - $(this).offset().top - (h / 2)) * (h > w ? (w / h) : 1);

      var direction = Math.round((((Math.atan2(y, x) * (180 / Math.PI)) + 180) / 90) + 3) % 4;

      /** check for direction **/
      switch (direction) {
          case 0:
              // direction top
              var slideFrom = {
                  "top": "-100%",
                      "right": "0"
              };
              var slideTo = {
                  "top": 0
              };
              var imgSlide = "0, 100";

              break;
          case 1:
              // direction right
              var slideFrom = {
                  "top": "0",
                      "right": "-100%"
              };
              var slideTo = {
                  "right": 0
              };
              var imgSlide = "-100, 0";

              break;
          case 2:
              // direction bottom
              var slideFrom = {
                  "top": "100%",
                      "right": "0"
              };
              var slideTo = {
                  "top": 0
              };
              var imgSlide = "0, -100";

              break;
          case 3:
              // direction left
              var slideFrom = {
                  "top": "0",
                      "right": "100%"
              };
              var slideTo = {
                  "right": 0
              };
              var imgSlide = "100, 0";

              break;
      }

      if (e.type === 'mouseenter') {
          var element = $(this);

          element.find(".info").removeClass("transform").css(slideFrom);
          element.find("img").addClass("transform-img").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1," + imgSlide + ")");

          setTimeout(function () {
              element.find(".info").addClass("transform").css(slideTo);
          }, 10);


      } else {
          var element = $(this);

          element.find(".info").addClass("transform").css(slideFrom);
          element.find("img").removeClass("transform-img").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1," + imgSlide + ")");

          setTimeout(function () {
              element.find("img").addClass("transform-img").css("transform", "matrix(1, 0, 0, 1,0,0)");
          }, 10);

      }
  });
```

---

HTML

```
<div id="gallery-container">
<div class="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" title="">
               <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
               <div class="info"><h3 class="heading">Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel ultricies sem. Praesent posuere, augue quis aliquet vestibulum, metus tellus vehicula sem, tincidunt luctus nisl sem et orci.</p></div>
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" title="">
               <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
               <div class="info"><h3 class="heading">Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel ultricies sem. Praesent posuere, augue quis aliquet vestibulum, metus tellus vehicula sem, tincidunt luctus nisl sem et orci.</p></div>
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" title="">
               <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
               <div class="info"><h3 class="heading">Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel ultricies sem. Praesent posuere, augue quis aliquet vestibulum, metus tellus vehicula sem, tincidunt luctus nisl sem et orci.</p></div>
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
<div class="gallery">
    <ul>
        <li> <a href="#" title="">
               <img src="http://th08.deviantart.net/fs71/200H/i/2012/190/b/7/bastique_graffiti_art_car__02__golf_mkv_r32_by_bastiqueart-d56k7iu.jpg" width="300" height="169" />
               <div class="info"><h3 class="heading">Lorem ipsum</h3>
        <p>dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nam vel ultricies sem. Praesent posuere, augue quis aliquet vestibulum, metus tellus vehicula sem, tincidunt luctus nisl sem et orci.</p></div>
            </a>

        </li>
    </ul>
</div></div>
```

Comment: i would have thought IE would have problems before chrome

Comment: As robust as chrome is it has a lot of issues when you start messing with things. Now granted there are only a few occasions where there are actually issues. Sometimes things just dont work.

Comment: I have no idea, i'm running it in chrome and its working perfectly fine 0.o

Comment: @Nicholas Young: its not moving the wrong way?

Comment: im using Chrome 36.0

Comment: It looks like its working correctly, and im also running 36